# How to check when ANY field on a record has been updated in a decision element

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a decision path in a flow that checks whether the status of an approval request is Submitted, Approved, or Rejected. I need another path (or way) that checks if any of the fields BESIDES the status has been updated. The issue I'm running into is whenever I update any field on the record it just goes down the path of whatever the status currently is. They all have notifications associated with them that need to pop which is why they need their own path.

How can I make sure the Updated path is followed when a record has already been created, and any other field besides Status has been changed? (It doesn't matter what the other fields were changed to)

Comment: Would the record have only gotten to that point in the flow if it was updated? If so you should be able to compare, eg `{!Record.Status}` to `{!Record__Prior.Status}`. If they're the same, then something besides Status changed. If they're different, then Status is at least one of the fields that changed.

Answer (score 0):

You may use ***$Record.fieldname*** "**is changed**" to true as a condition before you enter your approval status check. Both the paths - TRUE and FALSE paths should connect to your Approval Status check element. You will need to explicitly add a condition check within that conditional element for every field. This is not recommended if you have to check more than 20 fields (just a rule of thumb and not a limit)

You may very well do this as an exit point for all the branches of Approval Status also

If you need to however check a lot of fields in the record, you may have to write an Apex Trigger and helper classes (or invocaable method from the flow) that use Schema methods to get values of every field except the Approval Status field